# ios 6 strange behavior on custom UITableViewCell initialization

Tags: ios6, uitableview

I have custom and very simple UITableViewCell.
I just want to init my table view by using new technique in ios 6, i.e. registering class and after deque cell with identifier.
So i have UITableViewController, inside the tableview i have one prototype cell , here is the image of it.[image]

at first i forgot to register the class in viewDidLoad method inside the Table View controller and it was working fine. here is the code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"customCellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

but in this case

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
```

is not called during the cell init process.

and the after i put the register class functionality inside the viewdidload.
here is the code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView registerClass:[CustomCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"customCellIdentifier"];

}
```

after it the  `- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier` starts invoking but in this case the cells are absolutely empty when i'm trying to debug , inside the initwithstyle method all the outlets are nil.
whats going on? what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have defined the cell as prototype cell for the table view in your nib/storyboard file, then you don't have to register it, that is done automatically. But in that case, `initWithCoder:` is called for cells instantiated from the nib/storyboard.